# Java: How to reduce the number of if-else statements where not possible to merge them

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Although my code is working perfectly as I want, but there are many if-else statements in my code so I want to ask is it possible to reduce if-else statements in this code

```
if ( nightPost(timePicker1.getValue().toString(), timePicker4.getValue().toString()) ) {
    if ( !teToTime.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("08:30",format)) ) {
        textField4.setStyle("");
        if(getDifference(timeKA, timeKB)<121 && getDifference(timeKA, timeKB)>59) {
            timePicker3.setStyle("");
            if ( range(timePicker1.getValue().toString(), timePicker2.getValue().toString(),
                timePicker3.getValue().toString(), timePicker4.getValue().toString())) {
                timePicker2.setStyle("");
                timePicker3.setStyle("");
                if( increaseTxt.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("11:01",format)) )
                {
                    textField5.setStyle("");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    textField5.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                timePicker2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: orange");
                return false;
            }                               
        }
        else {
            timePicker3.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        textField4.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
        return false;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: I think you should ask this on codeReview.stackexchange...

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is doing, but here are some general pointers: fail early, maybe use switch/case or a map (for example for the colors), ternary operator, fetch information first, ...

Comment: My advice is not to mix English and another language throughout the code. It could the first step of improvement. This will help to understand your logic.

Comment: @tvelykyy changed it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace Nested Conditional with 
[Guard Clauses](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)

```
if (!nightPost(timePicker1.getValue().toString(), timePicker4.getValue().toString()) ) {
    return false;
}
if ( teToTime.isAfter(LocalTime.parse("08:30",format)) ) {
    textField4.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
    return false;
}
textField4.setStyle("");
if ( !(getDifference(timeKA, timeKB) < 121 && getDifference(timeKA, timeKB) > 59) ) {
    timePicker3.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
    return false;
}
timePicker3.setStyle("");
if ( !range(timePicker1.getValue().toString(), timePicker2.getValue().toString(), 
            timePicker3.getValue().toString(), timePicker4.getValue().toString()) ) 
{
    timePicker2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: orange");
    return false;
}
timePicker2.setStyle("");
timePicker3.setStyle("");
if ( !increaseTxt.isBefore(LocalTime.parse("11:01",format)) ) {
    textField5.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
    return false;
}
textField5.setStyle("");
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the term "Guard Clauses"! I never knew the proper term; in my comment above I referred to it as "fail early".

Comment: Please don't simply post a link containing the description. Those link can die redering your answer as obsolet. See [answer] about the link in answers.